How can you filter out a column and create a new data frame
Please write code create a new dataframe called "df2" to extract from df1 observations where the value in column "purpose" is "house". In other words, please filter df1 where purpose = "house", and save that new dataframe as "df2".
enter image description here

df2 = df1[df1["purpose"]=="house"].drop(["purpose"], axis=1)

